# Setting default-directory does not change find-file directory

Tags: files, find-file, directories

I try to set a default path for opening a file via `C-x C-f` by adding the following to my `.emacs`:

```
(setq default-directory "~/some_dir/")
```

However, after I launch `Emacs` in some directory, the find-file directory is always reset to the current working directory when I do `C-x C-f`.

Is there something else I need to configure to enforce this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation:

> `default-directory` is a variable defined in ‘C source code’. Its value
>   is "~/" Local in buffer *scratch*; global value is nil
>
> Automatically becomes permanently buffer-local when set.   This
>   variable is safe as a file local variable if its value   satisfies the
>   predicate 'stringp'.
>
> Documentation: Name of default directory of current buffer. To
>   interactively change the default directory, use command ‘cd’.

So, the `default-directory` variable, is the "current" directory, for the current buffer. And visiting any file or any directory, changes the `default-directory` for that buffer.

**EDIT**

You can achieve what you want by:

- adding `(cd "/some/dir/")` in yout init file.
- using a hook: `(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'(lambda () (setq default-directory (expand-file-name "/some/dir/"))))`
- writing a custom function that will `(cd "/some/dir/")` before finding file.

Comment: So if `default-directory` does not do what I want, how can I set a fixed directory for `C-x C-f`?

Comment: @MLister answer edited.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running emacs from a shortcut in Windows, you can edit the properties of the shortcut and set the `Start in` property to be the directory you'd like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>,<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to start from.

[image: shortcut properties dialog box]