# Troubleshooting: changing default folder in .emacs not working

Tags: init-file, find-file, directories

I am trying to make emacs start on the folder where all my orgfiles are saved. I achieved this in my windows machine by changing the "Start In" field of the shortcut properties, as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs).

However I haven't been able to make the changes in my `.emacs` file have any effect on this matter on my ubuntu machine. I am still left in my home folder when emacs is opened. I have tried several options such as the ones [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60464/changing-the-default-folder-in-emacs) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18723/setting-default-directory-does-not-change-find-file-directory/18724#18724?newreg=5f82fb84474e4e1ca2ba5dfb9ccd1ee3). For clarity I'll write them below:

```
;; Efforts to change default emacs folder
;;(cd (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Dropbox/orgs/"))
;;(cd "~/Dropbox/orgs/")
;;(setq default-directory (concat (getenv "HOME") "/Dropbox/orgs/"))
;;(setq default-directory "~/Dropbox/orgs/")
;;(add-hook 'find-file-hook #'(lambda () (setq default-directory (expand-file-name "~/Dropbox/orgs/"))))
```

Any tips on how can I go about this? I am using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "have any effect".  E.g. with the `(setq default-directory "~/Dropbox/orgs/")`, what failed to behave like you expected?

Comment: @Stefan thanks for giving it a look. I have edited the question as i was not clear. But basically I am sill left in my home folder no matter which method I tried to use to make emacs open in `~/Dropbox/orgs/` as default (or after C+x C+f)

Comment: maybe have a look here: https://superuser.com/questions/249525/how-to-change-the-default-directory-in-emacs

Comment: @PicaudVincent Thanks for the link. That was definitely the answer. None of the alternatives I tried worked since the startup screen changed "default directory back to the one where the welcome screen files are to be found". After adding `(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)`to my `.emacs` file they worked. I don't know the course of action here, if you'd like to make it an answer I'll gladly accept. I don't think it is a duplicate since the other question was on super user..

Comment: @brodoll that's very kind of you. I have written my answer with the right link. I all cases I am happy it solved your problem, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to https://superuser.com/a/478766/770454, one must disable startup-screen:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

> I think that the default welcome screen with the links to the tutorial
>   etc, changes the default directory back to the one where the welcome
>   screen files are to be found.

Comment: really helpful!