# default directory is not working in Windows

Tags: init-file, find-file, directories

I am trying to set the default directory to `D:/` by

```
(setq default-directory "D:/")
```

but when I type `c-x c-f`, it is showing `D:\software\emacs\bin`, which is the installation directory.

Comment: `default-directory` is buffer-local. I *suspect* you are running that code in your init file, and imagining it will affect all buffers, but that is incorrect. What is your goal (in detail)?

Comment: My goal is to go to default directory, in my case `D:/` where I have `D:/Documents`, `D:/programs`, etc., folders. Now, I have type it manually by removing the `D:/software/emacs/bin` directory, which I feel little bit boring. Yes, I want to run this code in `init-file`. Is there any other options?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is indeed likely the same as the one in [Setting default-directory does not change find-file directory](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18723) but here's a "solution" for your specific case:

`C-x C-f` shows you say `D:/software/emacs/bin/` and you want to open, say, `D:/Documents/mynotes.org`, then just type something like `/d/mynot TAB RET` and you should be done.  This is because `//` in this kind of file prompt is treated to mean "ignore everything before the `//`".  Just typing `/` should already make this clear by coloring the `/software/emacs/bin/` in grey.